# awk exit code if regular expression did not match

Tags: awk, regular-expression, gawk

I want to get exit code 1 if the 4th column did not match the regular expression, but it seems that awk will return 0, even though the regular expression did not match.

Any idea how to make awk return 1 if the regexp did not match?

```
root@server:~# netstat -nap|grep "LISTEN\b"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:873                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1144/rsync          
tcp        0      0 1.2.3.4.5:53                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25213/named         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25213/named         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      28888/sshd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9686                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1150/stunnel        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      25213/named         
root@server:~# netstat -nap|grep "LISTEN\b"|awk '$4 ~ /:80$/ {print $NF}'
root@server:~# echo $?
0
```

Comment: like so `awk 'condition{exit 1}'`?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Exit-Statement.html

Comment: @spasic: You can't do like that. In this case the condition is `the 4th column did not match the regular expression`, so it can exit immediately at the start if the 1st line does not match the condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set a variable to hold the return code, then negate the variable before quitting:

```
netstat -nap    |
grep "LISTEN\b" |
awk '$4 ~ /:80$/ {rc = 1; print $NF}; END { exit !rc }'
```

If you don't need `\b`, then you can remove `grep` part:

```
netstat -nap | awk '/LISTEN/ && $4 ~ /:80$/ {rc = 1; print $NF}; END { exit !rc }'
```

Comment: Or you can set the variable beforehand: `'BEGIN { rc=1 } $1=="foo" { print $0; rc=0; exit } END { exit rc }'`

Answer (score 18):

for me, this is awk's unforgiveable sin; if in need of an error status, I pipe to grep dot, as opposed to the awk gymnastics above

```bsh
$ date | awk '/Fri/'
Fri May 29 21:26:18 EDT 2020
$ date | awk '/Fri/' | grep .
Fri May 29 21:27:11 EDT 2020
$ echo $?
0
$ date | awk '/Mon/' | grep .
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: I like this more than the original solution.

Comment: smart man ^^ ;)